# When an electron is in superposition what happens to its charge?

Tags: electrons, charge, superposition

Hi my question is simple, what happens to the charge of an electron when it is in superposition, I am saying this because when orbitals of electrons are in superposition they still have charge to make bonds, but what excactly is happening there with the charge?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "happening" here. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I mean is the charge distributed in the "shape" of an orbital, or to say it differently are orbitals charged?